# error starting my hadoop namenode

Tags: hadoop, configuration, port, startup

I want to implement a Pseudo-Distributed hadoop system on my ubuntu machine.But I cannot start the namenode(others like jobtracker can be started normally).
my start command is :

```
./hadoop namenode -format
./start-all.sh
```

I checked the namenode log located in logs/hadoop-mongodb-namenode-mongodb.log

```
 65 2013-12-25 13:44:39,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec cl    ock time, 1 cycles
 66 2013-12-25 13:44:39,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
 67 2013-12-25 13:44:39,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec c    lock time, 1 cycles
 68 2013-12-25 13:44:39,799 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
 69 2013-12-25 13:44:39,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
 70 2013-12-25 13:44:39,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort9000 registered.
 71 2013-12-25 13:44:39,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort9000 registered.
 72 2013-12-25 13:44:39,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
 73 2013-12-25 13:44:39,847 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
 74 2013-12-25 13:44:39,878 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
 75 2013-12-25 13:44:39,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
 76 2013-12-25 13:44:39,888 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
 77 2013-12-25 13:44:39,889 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:mongodb cause:java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 78 2013-12-25 13:44:39,889 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicationMonitor thread received InterruptedExceptionjava.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
 79 2013-12-25 13:44:39,890 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager: Interrupted Monitor
 80 java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
 81     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 82     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager$Monitor.run(DecommissionManager.java:65)
 83     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
 84 2013-12-25 13:44:39,890 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number o    f syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0
 85 2013-12-25 13:44:39,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: closing edit log: position=4, editlog=/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs.name.dir/current/edits
 86 2013-12-25 13:44:39,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: close success: truncate to 4, editlog=/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs.name.dir/current/edits
 87 2013-12-25 13:44:39,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 9000
 88 2013-12-25 13:44:39,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down
 89 2013-12-25 13:44:39,909 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 90     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 91     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:174)
 92     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:139)
 93     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
 94     at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
 95     at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:602)
 96     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:517)
 97     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:395)
 98     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 99     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
100     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
101     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:395)
102     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:337)
103     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
104     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
105     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
106 
107 2013-12-25 13:44:39,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
108 /************************************************************
109 SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at mongodb/192.168.10.2
110 ************************************************************/
                                                                                                                                                                                 110,1         Bot
 63 2013-12-25 13:44:39,796 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
 64 2013-12-25 13:44:39,796 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
 65 2013-12-25 13:44:39,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec cl    ock time, 1 cycles
 66 2013-12-25 13:44:39,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
 67 2013-12-25 13:44:39,797 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec c    lock time, 1 cycles
 68 2013-12-25 13:44:39,799 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
 69 2013-12-25 13:44:39,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
 70 2013-12-25 13:44:39,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort9000 registered.
 71 2013-12-25 13:44:39,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort9000 registered.
 72 2013-12-25 13:44:39,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Namenode up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
 73 2013-12-25 13:44:39,847 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
 74 2013-12-25 13:44:39,878 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
 75 2013-12-25 13:44:39,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
 76 2013-12-25 13:44:39,888 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
 77 2013-12-25 13:44:39,889 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:mongodb cause:java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 78 2013-12-25 13:44:39,889 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicationMonitor thread received InterruptedExceptionjava.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
 79 2013-12-25 13:44:39,890 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager: Interrupted Monitor
 80 java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
 81     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 82     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager$Monitor.run(DecommissionManager.java:65)
 83     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
 84 2013-12-25 13:44:39,890 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number o    f syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0
 85 2013-12-25 13:44:39,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: closing edit log: position=4, editlog=/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs.name.dir/current/edits
 86 2013-12-25 13:44:39,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: close success: truncate to 4, editlog=/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs.name.dir/current/edits
 87 2013-12-25 13:44:39,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 9000
 88 2013-12-25 13:44:39,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down
 89 2013-12-25 13:44:39,909 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 90     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 91     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:174)
 92     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:139)
 93     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
 94     at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
 95     at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:602)
 96     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:517)
 97     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$1.run(NameNode.java:395)
 98     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 99     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
100     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
101     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:395)
102     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:337)
103     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
104     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
105     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
106 
107 2013-12-25 13:44:39,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

This is the error message.It seems obviously , port number went wrong!
And below is my conf file:
core-site.xml

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  2 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
  3 <configuration>
  4 <property>
  5 <name>fs.default.name</name>
  6 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  7 </property>
  8 </configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
  1 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  2 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
  3 
  4 <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
  5 <configuration>
  6      <property>
  7               <name>dfs.replication</name>
  8                <value>1</value>
  9      </property>
 10 
 11      <property>
 12              <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
 13              <value>/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs.name.dir</value>
 14      </property>
 15 
 16      <property>
 17              <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
 18              <value>/var/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/dfs.data.dir</value>
 19      </property>
 20 </configuration>
```

No matter how I change the port to others and restart hadoop ,the error exists all the same!
Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What is the output of `jps` command after this?

Comment: Hello,I use jps ,It show a SecondaryNamenode and Datanode,So I killed all processes it shows.Error continues...

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove hdfs data directory and instead of formatting namenode before starting hdfs, start hdfs first and check `jps` output. If everything was OK, then try to format namenode and recheck. If still there was a problem give me the log details.

**P.S:** Do not kill the processes. Just use `stop-all.sh` or whatever you should to stop hadoop.

Comment: I did as you asked.After I started hdfs using start-dfs.sh and type jps,27980 DataNode
28247 SecondaryNameNode
28465 Jps

Comment: I did as you told me.I start hdfs using command start-dfs.sh,and I use jps to check is ,result shows that DataNode process and SecondaryNameNode process is up ,nothing else.And then I format hdfs,the output of jps doesn't change!

Comment: Since I justed started hdfs,so namenode doesn't have any log.

Comment: Namenode did not start, so it should have a log file containing error!

Comment: No no no.As you told me ,I just started hdfs.not including namenode.

Comment: I did as you told me ,all the same.Before I start hadoop.I remove the data directory.

Comment: Could you please remove all the log files, do this again and once again look at namenode logs? I just want to be sure about exceptions.

Comment: Hi ,to make a more detailed discussion ,may I have your email address?

Comment: Hi , I tried every thing, including remove the whole hadoop directory and extract a new one from a jar file downloaded from the official website,problems is still there.

Comment: You can move this discussion to chat so we continue it there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43870/discussion-between-vico-wu-and-sam)

Answer (score 0):

The datanode on one of the slave machines in my cluster was throwing a similar exception with port binding:

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I noticed that the default web interface port of datanode i.e. 50075 was already bind to another application:

```
[ap2]-> netstat -an | grep -i 50075
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.1:45674              10.0.1.1:50075              ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.1:50075              10.0.1.1:45674              ESTABLISHED
[ap2]->
```

I have changed the Datanode web interface in `conf/hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
<value>10.0.1.1:50080</value>
<description>Datanode http port</description>
</property>
```

This helped to resolve the issue, similarly you can change the default address and port where the web interface listens by setting `dfs.http.address` in `conf/hadoop-site.xml`, e.g. localhost:9090, but ensure that port is available.